# Get coordinates of points after `Translate[]`

Tags: graphics, coordinate-transformation

Suppose I have some small set of points `Pts` in 3D space:

```
Pts = Point[#] & /@ {{RandomReal[], RandomReal[], 
     RandomReal[]}, {RandomReal[], RandomReal[], RandomReal[]}};
```

Then, I apply `Translate[]` to make more points, for instance:

```
translatedPoints = Graphics3D@Translate[Pts, Tuples[Range[4], 3]]
```

[image]

The question is, how do I get the coordinates of the new set of points from the `translatedPoints` object? (as a list of points {{$x1, y1, z1$},..,{$xn, yn, zn$}})

Thanks!

Comment: use `Point[Join @@ (TranslationTransform[#][First /@ Pts] & /@ 
   Tuples[Range[4], 3])]` instead of `Translate[Pts, Tuples[Range[4], 3]`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1.** With a slightly different way to use `Translate` we can use [`Normal`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Normal.html) on translated points:

```
translatedPoints2 = Graphics3D[Translate[Pts, #] & /@ Tuples[Range[4], 3]]; 

translatedPoints2[[1]] // Short[#, 10] &
```

[image]

```
tpts = Join @@ Normal[translatedPoints2[[1]]];

tpts[[All, 1]] // Short[#, 15] &
```

[image]

**2.** Alternatively, you can post-process your `translatedPoints` before using `Normal` to get the same result:

```
tpts == Join @@ Normal[translatedPoints[[1]] /. 
   Translate[a_, tr_] :> (Translate[a, #] & /@ tr) ]
```

> ```
>  True
> ```

**3.** Post-process your `translatedPoints` using [`TranslationTransform`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TranslationTransform.html):

```
tpts[[All, 1]] == 
 Join @@ (translatedPoints[[1]] /. 
    Translate[a_, tr_] :> (TranslationTransform[#][First /@ a] & /@ tr))
```

> ```
>  True
> ```