# Get coordinates of Translated Polygon

Tags: graphics, regions, computational-geometry

I have many polygons of the following form that I wish to do more complicated processing and analysis based on it's updated location (such as relationships between geometries).

```
Translate[Polygon[{{0, 0}, {0, 50}, {100, 50}, {100, 0}}], {954, 840}]
```

I thought I had found my solution of how to recover the coordinates of a translated `Polygon` from [an earlier thread](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/220985/get-coordinates-of-points-after-translate) about `Points`. However, when I tried to applied `Normal` M12.1 just returns the expression again.

```
Normal[Translate[Polygon[{{0, 0}, {0, 50}, {100, 50}, {100, 0}}], {954, 840}]]
```

I've tried some more complicated ways to extract the coordinates from a `Graphics` object to no avail. Does anyone have any suggestions about how they would recover the `Polygons` updated extents?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
translateToNormal[t_Translate] := TranslationTransform[#2] /@ # & @@ t

tp = Translate[Polygon[{{0, 0}, {0, 50}, {100, 50}, {100, 0}}], {954, 840}]

translateToNormal[tp]
```

> ```
>  Polygon[{{954, 840}, {954, 890}, {1054, 890}, {1054, 840}}]
> ```

Alternatively,

```
translateToNormal2 = # /. Translate -> (TranslationTransform[#2] /@ # &) &;

translateToNormal2 @ tp
```

> ```
>  Polygon[{{954, 840}, {954, 890}, {1054, 890}, {1054, 840}}]
> ```

```
Graphics[{FaceForm[], EdgeForm[{AbsoluteThickness[10], Red}], translateToNormal[tp],
  EdgeForm[{Thin, Black}], tp}]
```

[image]

To get the coordinates:

```
normalCoords[t_Translate] := TranslationTransform[#2] @ #[[1]] & @@ t
normalCoords[tp]
```

> ```
> {{954, 840}, {954, 890}, {1054, 890}, {1054, 840}}
> ```

Comment: It works thanks. I wasn't able to reverse what `#2` and `#` are actioning upon?

Answer (score 0):

**Using `TransformedRegion`:**

```
Clear["Global`*"];
poly = Polygon[{{0, 0}, {0, 50}, {100, 50}, {100, 0}}];
tvec = {954, 840};

tpoly = TransformedRegion[poly
   , TranslationTransform[tvec]];
```

---

*Results:*

```
PolygonCoordinates[tpoly]
```

> {{954, 840}, {954, 890}, {1054, 840}, {1054, 890}}

```
RegionQ /@ {poly, tpoly}
```

> {True, True}

```
Graphics[{Red, poly, Blue, tpoly
  , Dashed, Black
  , Arrow[{RegionCentroid@poly
    , RegionCentroid@poly + {tvec[[1]], 0}}]
  , Arrow[{RegionCentroid@poly + {tvec[[1]], 0}
    , RegionCentroid@tpoly}]
  }]
```

[image]

---

More operations can be cascaded using a `Dot` operator. For example, a rotation:

```
upoly = TransformedRegion[poly
   , TranslationTransform[tvec] . RotationTransform[π/4]];

PolygonCoordinates@upoly
```

> {{954 - 25 Sqrt[2], 840 + 25 Sqrt[2]}, {954, 840}, {954 + 25 Sqrt[2],
> 840 + 75 Sqrt[2]}, {954 + 50 Sqrt[2], 840 + 50 Sqrt[2]}}